# Disabling/Enabling a oracle apex Tabular Form Attribute based on the value selected in another attribute

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a tabular form attribute which is a select list with static values Yes/no and another 2 attributes of Date and display.
My requirement is when i select "No" from the Select List, Date attribute should be enabled and Display attribute should be Disabled and If "Yes" From select list Display attribute should be enabled and Date attribute should be Disabled.

```
Dynamic Action: 
Created a Dynamic action:
event = Change
Selection Type =  Jquery selector
Jquery selector = `select[name='f06']`
Action = Execute javascript Code

var el = this.triggeringElement.id;
var row = el.split("_")[1];
if ($v(el) == "N") {
// disable the field
$x_disableItem("f04_" + row, true);
}
else {
// enable the field
$x_disableItem("f04_" + row, false);
}
```

Dynamic action Working perfectly for already created Rows, But not while i am trying to add new Row by selecting Add row.

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=38210:LOGIN_DESKTOP:115699939041356

App 38210. Apex 4.2.6
Workspace/username/password : nani4850
```

Kindly help me out experts!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a blank row involves a partial page refresh, so the `Event Scope` of your dynamic action needs to be changed from `Static` to `Dynamic` in order for the change event handler to remain bound to the triggering elements.

You'll now find you have problems submitting new records, but if you're having difficulty, that's for another question!